# Apache Kafka: Java Producer reusability

Tags: asynchronous, messaging, apache-kafka

Does anybody know if

> kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer

can be reused among several method invocations (e.g. several send(...)) or it should be closed each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can surely be reused. `Producer` creation is pretty slow operation because it requires establishing connection to all partitions (and probably zookeeper). So, Producers should be reused when possible.